Why isn't my active condition statement working?
I am having some trouble while creating my pagination page using react-bootstrap. I am trying to apply condition for active but it is not working.
<Pagination.Item 
                // active={x+1===page}
                active={false}
                >
                    {x+1} 
</Pagination.Item>

All pagination status is showing active on UI.
How can I apply condition on active.

Looking at the bit of code you have provided, I have to surmise that
your component looks something like this..
[0, 1, 2, 3].map(x => (<Pagination.Item active={x+1===page}>
                        {x+1} 
                       </Pagination.Item>)
)

If that is the case, you are missing a key property on the element.  Something along the lines of this..
[0, 1, 2, 3].map(x => (<Pagination.Item active={x+1===page} key={x}>
                        {x+1} 
                       </Pagination.Item>)
)

The key needs to be a completely unique value, and is required so that react can keep track of the element in an array and render/update them as they change. Lack of a key prop can lead to bugs when the component state or properties update.

Pagination.Item is inside a parent component, which already hold the key.  The issue doesn't seem to be because of the key.
